# How can I declare a pointer to a Map<String, Set<String>>?

Tags: java

I am wondering how I can create an empty map of sets in Java.

Right now, I am trying to do this as follows, but running into a static error.

```
Map<String, Set<String>> MapOfSets = new HashMap<String, Set<String>()>;
```

What is the correct syntax to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax for creating a new instance is `new ClassName<generic spec>([arguments])`. Even if you don't want to pass any arguments to the constructor, you still need to use the parentheses. Your code has a typo - the argument list should come **after** the angular brackets, not inside them.

```
Map<String, Set<String>> mapOfSets = new HashMap<String, Set<String>>();
```

Note that since Java 7 you can use empty angular brackets (["the diamond"](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/language/type-inference-generic-instance-creation.html)), and allow Java to infer the generic type arguments without having to reiterate them in both the deceleration and the new instance creation:

```
Map<String, Set<String>> mapOfSets = new HashMap<>();
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the parentheses. `Map<String, Set<String>> MapOfSets = new HashMap<String, Set<String>>();`

Answer (score -1):

```
Map<String, Set<String>> MapOfSets = new HashMap<String, Set<String>>();
```